# How can I check I run the Commons profile?

Tags: 7, distributions

Yesterday I installed Drupal Commons on http://campus-24.com/. The version was grabbed from http://commons.acquia.com/home, but I am not very sure I have chosen the Drupal Commons installation profile.

In general the installation ends up with the appearance of exactly the same theme that is shown on http://commons.acquia.com/home.

It is pretty interesting that the above mentioned site does not feel/look, and it does not behave as a Commons. In short: The look and feel, and the behavior of the site is totally neurotic! If I look in the administrative area, I have only the following 6 themes in the system to choose between:

- Bluemarine
- Chameleon
- Marvin
- Garland
- Minnelli
- Pushbutton

So I guess there isn't a clear evidence that I have installed the wrong profile, the Drupal standalone installation profile, and not the Commons profile. Where can I have a closer look at which profile is active?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The profile used to install the site is stored in the variable `install_profile`. There's a few different ways you can see the value:

- Pop into the `variable` table in your database and search for `install_profile`:

  ```
  select value from variable where name='install_profile';
  ```
- Install the Devel module and visit `mysite.com/devel/variable`
- Put this custom code in a template file somewhere:

  ```
  <?php print variable_get('install_profile', 'No install profile found.'); ?>
  ```

Hope that helps

Comment: **update:** thx for the hints - finally got it: i after several trials i ported over a installation of the drupal commons 6x24 that was installed smoothley on the local lampp. See  here the results: http://schulcenter.org/?q=home 

looks that went all well; many many thanks for all your help! Greetings